# Format cell to have a bulleted list of items, Format? Formula?

Tags: php, excel-formula, html-lists, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel and generating the excel just fine but I have some data in CSV format and wanted to know if I could display it as a Bullet List.

Example of what I have:

```
some, data, in, cvs, format
```

This is what I would like

> • some
>  • data
>  • in
>  • cvs
>   • format

Is there a format or formula I could use?

UPDATE:

I saw this formula but I can't get it to work

```
=CHAR(149)&" "&C2&CHAR(10))
```

Comment: do you mean when you export it from CSV to Excel or just take the data and make a list with it?

Comment: Just take the data and make a list

Comment: Do you want the list contained inside of a single cell?

Comment: yes, I have several cells and a particular row I have the CSV Data which I would like to display as the bullet/unordered list

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your spreadsheet looks like this:

```
      A      B         C      D       E
1     some  data      in     csv    format
2     • some                
3     • data
4     • in
5     • csv             
6     • format
```

In cells A2 through A6, I put this formula:

```
=CHAR(149)&" "&OFFSET($A$1,0,ROW()-2)&CHAR(10)
```

However, if you have the entire comma separated list in one cell (I'm assuming A1 for now), use this formula:

```
=CHAR(149)&" "&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(10)&CHAR(149))
```

Then increase the vertical height of the cell and turn text wrapping on. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Have you had a chance to try this out?

Comment: sorry not yet but this is for my next project